# how to get getVisibleItems in time order (or how to get the previous item) in visjs timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I need to create a customized Horizontal Axis label for my timeline chart. When two days are very close and chart is small. The two Horizontal Axis labels get overlapped. I am wondering how can I skip one or two labels when there is overlap?

The way I am doing is getting the vis-dot location and then create a div for the label above vis-dot location

```
var labeloffset = $(".vis-item.vis-dot."+item.id).offset().left;
```

I use getVisibleItems() methods to get all visible items. But the problem is that it is not in time order.

var allVisableTtems = timeline.getVisibleItems();

I need help in two aspects:

1. get the visibleItems in time order. 
   ie, the earliest item in the front of the allVisableTtems list  and lastest item at end of the allVisableTtems list
2. Is there any way I can get the previous item at the timeline chart

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do sorting of items and getting previous items by direct manipulation on the data itself.

```
var ids = timeline.getVisibleItems();
var sortedVisibleItems = items.get(ids).sort(function (a,b) { 
  return a.start > b.start ? 1 : a.start < b.start ? -1 : 1
});

var index = sortedVisibleItems.indexOf(someItem);
var prevItem = sortedVisibleItems[index - 1];
```

You could also create some linked list yourself by adding fields `prevId` and `nextId` to every item or something like that.